# Sufficient condition for linear separability of a boolean function on $n$ variables

Tags: co.combinatorics, machine-learning

This is a cross-post of two recent questions at math.stackexchange without answers: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843357/573047) and [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4695646/573047).

A boolean function on an $n$-dimensional hypercube is [linearly separable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability) when the convex hulls of the points evaluating to $0$ and $1$ respectively are disjoint.

A necessary condition is that any rectangle (not only the faces) formed by $4$ points of the hypercube is linearly separable.

**Is this condition also sufficient?**

I have tested that the number of linearly separable boolean functions ([OEIS A000609](https://oeis.org/A000609)) on $n \le 4$ variables is equal to the number of hypercubes with all rectangles formed by $4$ vertices linearly separable (these ones counted using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851134/573047) and [this software](https://tio.run/##jVXbctpADH1ef4VKBgYH05jcHgpmph/QPmeG8uAr8dhsiG0SmA7fTnVZG2yaSfxgS9pzJK20K4fjVRgej1epDvNtFMOsrKL05fvz3Do3FaledW1RngYXtlRXZLOuojhJdQy/fj79VreuZeECvAXDrS7TlY4jyF/0CoLEga5l6wBhtXyuX23rr6VIzMADdypygfJkalkqeSlgSJaUV/EzA42f0ci2FBJVmsDwdZEuUVUqg5EHBfFUAbMZ@1AHVDtJrMV9x1wRkfxlGOTu1gSoEBsk7EfFeRmLNYOxh5hpA9hOlWIMOqfIWe2sggEGpPSKuNoWmgOLo9qCuz5IBdd@qnm7frEKHQif/QKuUX5bLJs66YvEqcyUgawHyZrU9fYCt9ntHXqtDXKzoPYtjbZrafuW5re0oKWFLS2qNUtpLMzdVKpA@4E5TKgOZRn6OhnytiZLB3r9qOfAQNtEwsSpOVhD3ihxNcw9eDDtkHV3l5hnKrZtTUL0GMG1eTzudu4sAIoGx7Daj2sODVXKHJTmGMohhUyOYcbHUIDXHjzSBrjS/CrzUrxZ6uZmg1esSoY9E6Mf/dE9aZPdnHPsobgnYeZJE0nhMAZSIwyAxNNlwAw5KOUsBMyNdeo7Js3dp7dkTqTOIXkXBr7Jxyc7FwfS@HSFCGb3qRJkL9/TKnyGIa4x2sBV6JcxuD9EUbtFtkTqGJPci4hxNiJNpgYUFLHPd6rhTzr8/9Hdj@m3Hbrb0CmRz8PffciffCX8/Yf0L2X/8AV6N3kSD/z2BUA4MQcnw2jXWMOOdbRvlqKzpZOVu3/jmfYfOGH@Mfi5j2j8P5hR5dD89/mW1oDgEhC0AOElIGwBoktAZEvVaIxIEp64GgxMTE@YovvwjfXg7GzXl7hdSKoj74885yXj8b6PRnLb2UyXdWBGlU2RXJvX1GkWeO6u797vXHzMPIA5TslHux5BBql5ZDhmpPTzXMaHZguBrda/5Hg83v8D)). Therefore the above condition is proven sufficient for $n \le 4$.

Using the suggestion on the below comment by @Fedor Petrov I was able to prove the conjecture for $n \le 5$ using [this updated software](https://tio.run/##jVbdb9owEH92/gqvFRU0dCSsq6YBlbbnrS97mcSiKZ/UJRiahBbU8bez@3BCXKYOHuK7@51/vjvbZ@KrWRzv9@dKx/k6SeW4rBK1fH9/67RNhdKz17YkV9GRTekKbc55kmZKp/L7l593Yui19a/ffgjfw5/jgLt8irprGG@uf1cyyvoSbZqHy8ee8@IIFOdyIr0RywXI/shxRLYsZBctilAYxlLD4Lo9R8BEoTLZfZyqAFQh5tKdyAI4RCHHY6IQO2A5rL6oiUFCjznKyBFl8gJgpCnSal1ompzmZXqwQHQ7zmgRKk1hhcUs7sv4PizkJchP06DJR49aC6vMh4SzYdsWZba2sNS8nA6DKVczeIXoJWCmVAp0Iz6w2HiuNts@fhYGXyHdXT1xY2lbSwstLbK02NISS1uVFRWXQvQCKDZmjLl4AeveQfcD3gyBKRjogUV77zVZYBjLGxiavYeSGQYScT@7Wl5Jv4fTBWZe4w0XnzIY6BzNicu4Xk6AHic2BSybuExKGF6dhYBkWQR5MFjBDaqy7hlEsgZzJ/mlz/q4q2uOhiPIfHOOQRibrcT0AzJxNMZzWHsOjz2H7IlFgNTBEUtK6BRoAiiFOU8E/7FxOjqC9qsutjCrQh241iiM@ezg15TpBVpBJj0U6dKQO0RJIEdjACxNAwgRL3Wl9DqlleBK4pfu1nmqE5W1pzfFf@Zg4Muz/reHDQOfSzUDL@Lo4LYyUj6rKr6XXUDr0OpJIg7LVHqfa1VspnPc6iuoxpZFWHPFkj9q3KIiDamLtFj8I5Z/kXhvkwyPSLyGBIM6LZQPb7D4p4Zy/QbJyfl8PInkOB1WdmYM2Q29ayg6mNxNyx6/srvbFpi0wLadL3UTBR2gwaQ5QTtzgJ36nD2FeQgT4InDlw1etbA3aoORBUY2GFtgbIOJBSY9U068XrzohCkuLsw6E57FeijfkR5Zd/PQz@z6UlqcFfLnpbnu5Aatg/retNUDXRerRy8YXqu8dN2R4RgMDAu/qd4mg1/PtAMCxaFXTrxNx/u0wf8Kpl/K21vp31ApKCDzOPjQ181T1zwSYOInzzlQauq9fdO6O3m@Jl5Nlh79HxCO/aDv938B) which took about $8$ minutes on my computer, which decreases to about $5$ minutes if I test the next boolean function on the rectangle where the previous one failed the linear separability test.

**UPDATE 2024-02-13**

Using [this software](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269865/100784) I was able to compute the expected value of $15028134$ for $n=6$ in $22$ hours, so now the conjecture is proven for $n \le 6$. Later this [other software](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270080/100784) did it even better in $2$ hours and $45$ minutes. However now it looks impossible to go further searching for a possible counterexample, unless a more advanced algorithm, exploiting some structure of the problem and with much lower computational complexity, is found.

**UPDATE 2024-02-16**

A [new software](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270106/100784), exploiting some symmetry, computed the case $n = 6$ in only $2$ seconds and the expected value $8378070864$ for $n = 7$ in $1$ hour and $19$ minutes. Therefore now the conjecture is true for $n \le 7$.

Comment: If a counterexample exists, you may consider the counterexample of minimal dimension $d$. Then on each of two parallel $(d-1)$-facets the functions are linearly separable, that is, have the form $[a_1x_1+....+a_nx_n+b>0]$ (where $[X]$ is 1 if the condition $X$ holds and 0 if not). The sets of such form look more handy then arbitrary sets, in particular for a computer search for a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is not sufficient. This is a counterexample for $n=9$:

3121716732950836191359193754534242007469797427570571637452595771886175474823117400353574287579547318923874761239430570584653046830442366504009727

It satisfies the rectangle condition, but is not linearly separable.

I found it by noticing that sets $a$

```
(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

and $b$

```
(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
```

were linearly inseparable, and also had the property that no rectangle with opposite corners in $a$ had any corners in $b$, and vice versa.

Here's some SageMath code to verify

````
x = 3121716732950836191359193754534242007469797427570571637452595771886175474823117400353574287579547318923874761239430570584653046830442366504009727

p = MixedIntegerLinearProgram(maximization=True, solver='PPL')
v = p.new_variable(real=True)
for i in range(512):
    s = sum(v[j]*((i>>j)&1) for j in range(9)) + v['c']
    if x&(1<<i):
        p.add_constraint(s >= 0)
        p.add_constraint(v['o'] <= s)
    else:
        p.add_constraint(s <= 0)
        p.add_constraint(v['o'] <= -s)
p.add_constraint(v['o'] <= 1)
p.set_objective(v['o'])
print(p.solve(), p.get_values(v)) # objective value of 0 means not separable

import itertools

def gen_rectangles(n):
    x = []
    for t in itertools.product([
        (0,0,0),
        (1,1,1),
        (0,0,1),
        (1,1,0),
        (0,1,0),
        (1,0,1),
    ], repeat=n):
        a = b = c = 0
        for a1, b1, c1 in t:
            a, b, c = a*2+a1, b*2+b1, c*2+c1
        if a < b < c:
            x.append((a, b, c, a^^b^^c))
    return x

for a,b,c,d in gen_rectangles(9):
    t = ((x>>a)&1, (x>>b)&1, (x>>c)&1, (x>>d)&1)
    if t in [(0,1,1,0), (1,0,0,1)]:
        print('Found bad rectangle:', a, b, c, d)
        break

```
````